# How to get checkbox value from state/props?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get value from my state, but the result is just [object Object], can anyone help me why this happen?

```
selectItems = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      this.setState({
        selected: e.target.value
      })
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }

render(){
const { productDetail } = this.props

<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox' value={productDetail} onChange={this.selectItems} />

}
```

Comment: It happens because `productDetail` is an object. Or you print it wrong. You need to show more of you code (see [mcve] for details.)

Comment: are you trying to check your checkbox? if you want the value of it just reference `this.props.productDetail`

Answer (score -1):

Your input element write the changes to State, but didn't reflect the changes from State to the element. That won't be helping you.
Your component also didn't provide props type checking, so that's causing to send the wrong info to this component's prop.

Answer (score -1):

Hi try this approach.

```
selectItems = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      this.setState({
        selected: e.target.value
      })
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }


  render() {
    let productDetail = [{name:"test"}];
    let value = [];
    productDetail.forEach(res => {
      value.push(
        <div>
          <input 
            type='checkbox' 
            id='checkbox'
            value={res.name} 
            onChange={this.selectItems} /> Select
      </div>
      )
    })
    return (<span>
        {value}
        {this.state.selected}
      </span> );
  }
}
```